# Avoid button click/ controls for datagridview; automatically display

Tags: c#, winforms

I don't want to use button controls I just want the data to be displayed and in gridview then transferred into excel as the code states. Is there a way to eliminate/skip over button control/click?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Sciclone UAC", "*.cfg*");
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {

            var query = from file in fileEntries
                        let doc = XDocument.Load(file)
                        let x = doc.Descendants("XAxisCalib").Single()
                        let y = doc.Descendants("YAxisCalib").Single()
                        let z = doc.Descendants("ZAxisCalib").Single()
                        select new
                        {

                            XMax = x.Element("Max").Value,
                            XMin = x.Element("Min").Value,
                            YMax = y.Element("Max").Value,
                            YMin = y.Element("Min").Value,
                            ZMax = z.Element("Max").Value,
                            ZMin = z.Element("Min").Value
                        }; 


            var bs3 = new BindingSource { DataSource = query };

            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs3;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp ;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pull the code out into functions:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Could add calls here
    LoadData();
    RunExcel();
}

// Remove this button click handler if desired
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LoadData();
}

// Remove this button click handler if desired
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   RunExcel();
}

private void LoadData()
{
    string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Sciclone UAC", "*.cfg*");
    foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
    {

        var query = from file in fileEntries
                    let doc = XDocument.Load(file)
                    let x = doc.Descendants("XAxisCalib").Single()
                    let y = doc.Descendants("YAxisCalib").Single()
                    let z = doc.Descendants("ZAxisCalib").Single()
                    select new
                    {

                        XMax = x.Element("Max").Value,
                        XMin = x.Element("Min").Value,
                        YMax = y.Element("Max").Value,
                        YMin = y.Element("Min").Value,
                        ZMax = z.Element("Max").Value,
                        ZMin = z.Element("Min").Value
                    }; 


        var bs3 = new BindingSource { DataSource = query };

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs3;
    }
}

private void RunExcel()
{
   Excel.Application xlApp ;
   Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
   Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
   object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

   xlApp = new Excel.Application();
   xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
   xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which button click are you trying to eliminate? To eliminate the button2 click, just subscribe to the dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete event and move the code there.

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
  // your excel code
}
```

To eliminate the button1 click, just move that code into the constructor...

Comment: I want to eliminate both buttons so their not activated by click but rather just happen on build.

Comment: Yeah, just move all the code to the constructor or, for the sake of clarity, take SwDevMan81's advice and move the code into separate, well-named methods that can be called from the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Just move your code around a bit and transfer data on the datasourcechanged event :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Add the handler for the DataSourceChanged event.
        dataGrid1.DataSourceChanged += new EventHandler(DataGrid1_DataSourceChanged);
        LoadGridData();
    }

    private void LoadGridData()
    {
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Sciclone UAC", "*.cfg*");
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {

            var query = from file in fileEntries
                        let doc = XDocument.Load(file)
                        let x = doc.Descendants("XAxisCalib").Single()
                        let y = doc.Descendants("YAxisCalib").Single()
                        let z = doc.Descendants("ZAxisCalib").Single()
                        select new
                        {

                            XMax = x.Element("Max").Value,
                            XMin = x.Element("Min").Value,
                            YMax = y.Element("Max").Value,
                            YMin = y.Element("Min").Value,
                            ZMax = z.Element("Max").Value,
                            ZMin = z.Element("Min").Value
                        }; 


            var bs3 = new BindingSource { DataSource = query };

            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs3;
        }
    }

    private void DataGrid1_DataSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid thisGrid = (DataGrid) sender;
        Excel.Application xlApp ;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```